# Array and object complexity and "selectors"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've seen multiple times people talking about `O(1)`, `O(n)` etc in questions but nobody tells what it means and how it works. I tried to search it online but I don't know what keywords to use..

**What does these mean and how it applies to situations?**

Please consider using these two simple examples and my questions in the spirit of this question.

---

### **Object:**

1. Time / performace difference for each level inward?
2. Difference between `.object` vs `['object']` in the concept of my
   question?

`pets.dogs` **or** `pets['dogs']`

`pets.dogs.collie` **or** `pets['dogs']['collie']`

`pets.dogs.collie.size` **or** `pets['dogs']['collie']['size']`

---

3. How does array affect this bunch *(if I know the key)*?

`pets.dogs.collie.color[2]` **and** `pets.dogs.collie.popularnames[56]`

---

4. How does array affect this bunch *(if I don't know the key and this is in `for` loop)*?

`pets.dogs.collie.color[i]` **and** `pets.dogs.collie.popularnames[i]`

---

```
var pets = {

    dogs: {
        chihuahua: { 
            color: ["black", "white"],
            size: "tiny",
            hunting: false,
            popularnames: [ /*100 names*/ ]
        },
        collie: { 
            color: ["brown", "white"],
            size: "medium",
            hunting: false,
            popularnames: [ /*100 names*/ ]
        },
        // etc
    },
    cats: {
        bengal: { 
            color: ["gray", "white"],
            size: "medium",
            fur: "short",
            popularnames: [ /*100 names*/ ]
        },
        birman: { 
            color: ["black", "white"],
            size: "medium",
            fur: "long",
            popularnames: [ /*100 names*/ ]
        },
        // etc
    }
}
```

**Bottom line question:**

5. Should I avoid complicated objects *(e.g many, many selectors)* and use multiple simpler ones?
6. Is array iteration performance worse if I iterate array *deep / 3-4 levels* inside the object?

---

### **Array:**

1. Time / performace difference for each level inward *(If I know the keys)*?

`pets[0]`

`pets[0][1]`

`pets[0][1][3]`

---

2. How does object affect this bunch *(if I know the key)*?

`pets[0][1][1]['somekey']`

---

```
var myArray = [

    0: [
        0: [
            0: [ /* 100 objects */ ],
            1: [ /* 100 objects */ ],
            2: [ /* 100 ints */ ],
            3: [ /* 100 ints */ ]
        ],
        1: [
            0: [ /* 100 objects */ ],
            1: [ /* 100 objects */ ],
            2: [ /* 100 ints */ ],
            3: [ /* 100 ints */ ]
        ],
        // etc
    ],
    1: [
        0: [
            0: [ /* 100 objects */ ],
            1: [ /* 100 objects */ ],
            2: [ /* 100 ints */ ],
            3: [ /* 100 ints */ ]
        ],
        1: [ 
            0: [ /* 100 objects */ ],
            1: [ /* 100 objects */ ],
            2: [ /* 100 ints */ ],
            3: [ /* 100 ints */ ]
        ],
        // etc
    ]
]
```

**Bottom line question:**

3. Should I avoid complicated arrays *(e.g many, many levels)* and use multiple simpler ones?

---

Comment: You have 9 questions within your question?

Comment: Look up "big o notation"

Comment: @krillgar I don't need an answer for each of those questions if you don't feel like answering them. I added these just to describe the situation and help you to answer my question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: None of your examples really touch on Big O notation at all. The `.` and `[]` accessor are both `O(1)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plain English explanation of Big O](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)

Comment: @MattBurland You just said how it touches that. :) That was my main concern: Difference between single accessor and multiple accessors in the spirit of Big O so that I could decide how build my arrays and objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an in-depth explanation of of your question regarding O(1),O(n), please see this [wikipedia article on Big_O_notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Arrays in Javascript are not associative, because everything in Javascript is an Object. I've found [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/) to be a nice reference of good practices.

Maybe I'm just lazy, but I tend to make a habit out of making my arrays as "shallow" as possible. Like the De La Soul joint, "3's the magic number" for me. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was actually the point of my question: **how should I build my objects / arrays?** Does _shallow_ perform better?

Comment: You are welcome. :) In my humble opinion, yes, shallow is better. In my own experiments, as the Javascript Garden section on arrays suggests, using the classic "for" loop is better for performance than the "for in" construct, i imagine no matter how "deep" you build the arrays.